# Strange segfault when using bash into Makefile

Tags: bash, gnu-make

I need to read a file line by line in a Makefile.
The following trigger a segfault :

```
all:
    @cat myFile.txt | while read -r line; do echo $$(line); done
```

Strangely the following works (print the content of the file) :

```
all:
    @cat myFile.txt | while read -r line; do echo $$line; done
```

Any idea of the cause of the problem ?

Comment: Shell variables can be enclosed in braces `${line}`; Make variables can be enclosed in either braces `${line}` or brackets `$(line)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, `$(line)` (that is, the code after being un-escaped by Make) isn't going to do what you expect. It is a [command substitution](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/CommandSubstitution) which will execute the literal command `line`, which may or may not be a command on your system.

In general, anything which either needs escape characters or which would have been written as more than one line in a shell script should probably be in a shell script. You'll save yourself headaches that way.